# Drupal Behaviors, Function Scope

Tags: 8, javascript

Hi sorry if this is a simple question, but I could not figure it out on [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview)

My question is about function scope, my code is as follows:

```
(function ($, Drupal){
  Drupal.behaviors.map = {
     attach: function (context, settings){
        var map;
        function initMap() {
           map = new google.maps.Map($('#map'), {
              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
              zoom: 8
           });
        }
      }
   };
 })(jQuery, Drupal);
```

In my theme.libraries.yml I have:

```
 https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/blah&callback=initMap: {type: external, attributes: {async: true}}
```

But on my console I get:

```
initMap is not a function
```

So my question is how to allow callbacks to reference to my function initMap?
It works if I do the less optimal way $(document).ready...

Comment: Drupal.mymodule.initMap or any of the gazillion JS approaches.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is a plain JavaScript question, for which the answer doesn't change just because you are using Drupal. `initMap()` is a nested function, so outside `Drupal.behaviors.map.attach()` is not visible, nor accessible. Move it outside the `Drupal.behaviors.map` object.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thanks! I understood what was going wrong now, fixed.